# Post data from Angular8 contains empty QueryDict but data in request.body in Django

Tags: django, angular, angular8

Here's my code in Angular8 which is accessing a view built in Django:

```
this.http.post('/api/insert', {'csv':this.csvContent}, httpOptions).subscribe();
```

I want the post data to contain a string which has contents in the form of csv

Here is my corresponding view in Django:

```
@csrf_exempt
def insert_table(request):
    logging.debug(request.body)
    logging.debug(request.POST)
    with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'data/table.csv', 'w') as file:
        file.write(request.POST.get('csv', 'a,b,c'))
    return JsonResponse({'csv': request.POST.get('csv', 'a,b,c')})
```

`request.POST` contains < QueryDict: {} >

while `request.body` contains `b'{"csv":"a,b,c\\r\\n1,2,1\\r\\n4,5,6\\r\\n1,7,1\\r\\n"}'` when I actually do a POST request from Angular

How do I use this?

Comment: use request.data instead